# array value goes back to old value after save button is clicked on swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitextfield, textfield

I am using array to save value from textfield and it does change the value but when i go back and try to save another value it saves in array[0] even tho I had previously saved value there.

`var myarray = ["","",""]` this code is outside the save button func so shouldn't it be updated when save button is clicked
I am using if and if else for my save button code to save value of textfeild in array.

```
 if myarray[0] == "" { myarray[0]= textfield.text}

else if myarray[1] == "" { myarray[1]= textfield2.text}

else if myarray[2] == "" { myarray[2]= textfield.text}
```

when I check if value of array index has changed it does show that it has changed but when I open another view controller and come back to save more value instead of saving it in myarray[2] it saves in myarray[0].

Could someone please help me understand what is going on.

thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you can show more parts of your codes to help us have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @hello88 If i am not wrong you need to add the text of text field at index0, textfield2.text at index 1 and  textfield.text at index 3. Right.?